# Remove characters from a cell array of strings (Matlab)

Tags: string, matlab, character, cell

I have a cell array of strings.  I need to extract say 1-to-n characters for each item.  Strings are always longer than n characters.  Please see:

```
data = { 'msft05/01/2010' ;
         'ap01/01/2013' }

% For each string, last 10 characters are removed and put it in the next column

answer = { 'msft' '05/01/2010' ;
           'ap'   '01/01/2013' }
```

Is there a vectorized solution possible?  I have tried using cellfun but wasn't successful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = { 'msft05/01/2010' ;
         'ap01/01/2013' };
for i = 1:length(data)
    s = data{i};
    data{i} = {s(1:end-10) s(end-9:end)};
end
```

Sorry, didn't notice that you need vectorized... Perhaps I can suggest only one-liner...

```
data = cellfun(@(s) {s(1:end-10) s(end-9:end)}, data, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Users can then do vertcat(data{:}) to get the final ans.